# Video is too short in Avconv -- but only when run as a crontab

Tags: php, shell, avconv

I'm working on a PHP script that creates half-hour videos, combining a 30-minute MP3 with a still-frame background image, and then putting it on YouTube through the Google API. It works great except when I run it from a crontab, and I can't figure out why.

It uses a shell command to run the following.

```
avconv -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i background.png -loglevel verbose -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -vf scale=\"trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720\" -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -y -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

When I run it from my shell, it produces a video just as long as the 30 minute MP3. But if I run it from any kind of crontab, the result is just a fraction of the full length as it will stop at about 3 or 4 minutes.

Typical output below for a failed result. What baffles me is that it's not that the script is aborted, and it doesn't seem to time out. Rather than stop, it keeps going and will upload the short, unfinished version to YouTube.

I thought it might be a shell environment problem, missing some part of the $PATH or variables. But even when I import all the env and path settings, it does not seem to work.

Is there some way to make sure the avconf (or ffmpeg) command continues all the way through and does not stop too early?

Typical output dump below from one of the times it fails: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ecaa77037926821dba19e9db5ccb3a10

(I used avconv because my host service claimed ffmpeg was deprecated and that I should use avconv instead. Could a library like PHP-FFMPEG be better for this?)

Comment: `I used avconv because my host service claimed ffmpeg was deprecated` this is completely incorrect, `avconv` was a branch of `ffmpeg` that was made due to a conflicting views between some developers, `ffmpeg` is very much alive and well, and the library you should be using.

Comment: Try putting your cmd-line into a a script and call that from your crontab. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have Linux here to test but... Won't the shell expand `*`?

Comment: Apparently there is a schism between avconv and ffmpeg and the result is this misleading message when run on ffmpeg Dreamhost's shared server: "The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv (see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead." Switchin' to FFMPEG!